# How to convert Pinescript version 2 to Version 4/5?

Tags: pine-script

How to convert following script to v5?

```
study("ADX/DI Histogram",overlay=false,scale=scale.left)

len = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=14)
th = input(title="threshold", type=integer, defval=25)

TrueRange = max(max(high-low, abs(high-nz(close[1]))), abs(low-nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0

SmoothedTrueRange = nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus

DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DX = abs(DIPlus-DIMinus) / (DIPlus+DIMinus)*100
ADX = sma(DX, len)
ve=DIPlus>(DIMinus+(DIPlus*10)/100)
ro=DIMinus>(DIPlus+(DIMinus*10)/100) and ADX>11 and ADX<=25
xve= DIPlus>(DIMinus+(DIPlus*10)/100) and ADX>22
xro=DIMinus>(DIPlus+(DIMinus*10)/100) and ADX>22
fl=DIPlus-DIMinus<abs(10) and ADX<15

di=25+(DIPlus-DIMinus)

cr = ADX <= 22 ? color(green, 80) : ADX <= 34 ? color(green, 60) : ADX <= 46 ? color(green, 35) : ADX <= 58 ? color(green, 5) : ADX <= 70 ? color(green, 0) : color(green, 0)
cg = ADX <= 22 ? color(maroon, 80) : ADX <= 34 ? color(maroon, 60) : ADX <= 46 ? color(maroon, 35) : ADX <= 58 ? color(maroon, 5) : ADX <= 70 ? color(maroon, 0) : color(maroon, 0)
//adxgrad = ADX <= 22 ? color(gray, 60) : ADX <= 34 ? color(gray, 50) : ADX <= 46 ? color(gray, 40) : ADX <= 58 ? color(gray, 30) : ADX <= 70 ? color(gray, 20) : color(gray, 0)

plot(di,style=columns,linewidth=4,color=di >= 25 ? cr : cg,transp=50,histbase=th,title="DI")
plot(di,style=line,linewidth=2,color=di >= 25 ? cr : cg,transp=50,histbase=th,title="DI Line")
plot(ADX, color=black, linewidth=1,transp=0, title="ADX")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [migration guide](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html) on how to upgrade your code to v3. Once you do that manually, you can upgrade it to v4 and v5 using the auto converter tool.

To upgrade your code to v3, you should know some changes like [self referenced variables are removed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed).

To fix self referencing, you can do:

```
SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange
```

The links I provided should give you enough information. Again, upgrade it to v3 manually then use the auto converter tool.